# Indexing An Ajax Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am creating an array from a database which provides location information.  This array is to be used to determine the nearest location to the users current one.  Below is my code and the data results:

```
// Locations Array Test
function locationArrayTest() {
    // Variables
    var functionReturn;
    // Ajax Call
    $.ajax({
        // URL
        url: 'queryPage.php?',
        // Data
        data: 'varObtainLocations=y',
        // Type
        type: 'GET',
        // Content
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // Data Type
        dataType: "text",
        // Async
        async: false,
        // Error
        error: function(xhr, strError){
            // Assign Function Return 
            functionReturn = 'No Activity';
        },
        // Success
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

This produces the following array:

```
[{
    "locationID": "9",
    "locationName": "Employee Residence",
    "locationLatitude": "34.47189",
    "locationLongitude": "-111.9896046999",
    "locationPlaceID": "EhIJHZ_sQTAMK4cRBzdWbQXyX7s"
}, {
    "locationID": "40",
    "locationName": "Tron Utah",
    "locationLatitude": "33.964212",
    "locationLongitude": "-118.3783589999",
    "locationPlaceID": "ChIJdywE4jq3woARoNfsUOFSfjY"
}, {
    "locationID": "39",
    "locationName": "Tron Enterprises",
    "locationLatitude": "33.735187",
    "locationLongitude": "-111.9579499999",
    "locationPlaceID": "ChIJwR6Udhx6K4cRwVBI0d9dAVE"
}]
```

In order for the function to provide the closest location to work in area needs to be indexed like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": -111.9896046999,
            "Latitude": 34.47189,
            "Location": "Location A"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 6.11499,
            "Latitude": 50.76891,
            "Location": "Location B"
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 6.80592,
            "Latitude": 51.53548,
            "Location": "Location C"
        }
    },
    "5": {
        "Position": {
            "Longitude": 13.36671,
            "Latitude": 52.54344,
            "Location": "Location D"
        }
    }
}
```

The remaining code is as follows:

```
    // Variables
var targetLocation;
// Obtain Log/Lat
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // Obtain Current Position Lat/Lon
    glbVar.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    glbVar.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    // Distance Object
    var distanceObj = [],
    i = 0;
    // Produce List
    $.each(locationArray, function (a,b) {
       distanceObj[i] = { distance: hesapla(glbVar.longitude, glbVar.latitude, b.Position.Longitude, b.Position.Latitude), location: b.Position.Location };
        ++i;
    });
    // Determine Distance
    distanceObj.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt(a.distance) - parseInt(b.distance)
    });
    // List Locations
    $.each(distanceObj, function(a,b) {
        $('#groups').append('<li>' + b.location + ': ' + b.distance + 'm</li>');
    });
    // Testing
    //console.log(distanceObj);
    //
    function hesapla(meineLongitude, meineLatitude, long1, lat1) {
        //
        erdRadius = 6371;
        //
        meineLongitude = meineLongitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        meineLatitude = meineLatitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        long1 = long1 * (Math.PI / 180);
        lat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);
        //
        x0 = meineLongitude * erdRadius * Math.cos(meineLatitude);
        y0 = meineLatitude * erdRadius;
        //
        x1 = long1 * erdRadius * Math.cos(lat1);
        y1 = lat1 * erdRadius;
        //
        dx = x0 - x1;
        dy = y0 - y1;
        //
        d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        // Function Retrun
        return Math.round(d * 1000);
    };
});
```

My question is how do I produce an array with an index as needed for the nearest location functions to work.  Any help is appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).
2. Iterate through your source and build the desired object.

The `jQuery.map()` way is slightly easier, but actually creates an array instead of your stated desire of an array-like object, but my guess is the array will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = [{"locationID":"9","locationName":"Employee Residence","locationLatitude":"34.47189","locationLongitude":"-111.9896046999","locationPlaceID":"EhIJHZ_sQTAMK4cRBzdWbQXyX7s"},{"locationID":"40","locationName":"Tron Utah","locationLatitude":"33.964212","locationLongitude":"-118.3783589999","locationPlaceID":"ChIJdywE4jq3woARoNfsUOFSfjY"},{"locationID":"39","locationName":"Tron Enterprises","locationLatitude":"33.735187","locationLongitude":"-111.9579499999","locationPlaceID":"ChIJwR6Udhx6K4cRwVBI0d9dAVE"}];

  var destination = $.map(source, function(item) {
    return {"Position" : {"Longitude" : item.locationLongitude, "Latitude" : item.locationLatitude, "Location": item.locationName}};
  });

});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery or absolutely need the the results in an object, you can write a simple loop that will build your object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var source = [{"locationID":"9","locationName":"Employee Residence","locationLatitude":"34.47189","locationLongitude":"-111.9896046999","locationPlaceID":"EhIJHZ_sQTAMK4cRBzdWbQXyX7s"},{"locationID":"40","locationName":"Tron Utah","locationLatitude":"33.964212","locationLongitude":"-118.3783589999","locationPlaceID":"ChIJdywE4jq3woARoNfsUOFSfjY"},{"locationID":"39","locationName":"Tron Enterprises","locationLatitude":"33.735187","locationLongitude":"-111.9579499999","locationPlaceID":"ChIJwR6Udhx6K4cRwVBI0d9dAVE"}];

  var destination2 = {};
  for(var index = 0; index < source.length; index++) {
    var item = source[index];
    destination2[index] = {"Position" : {"Longitude" : item.locationLongitude, "Latitude" : item.locationLatitude, "Location": item.locationName}};
  }     
});
```

This example shows you both ways: http://jsbin.com/cuguqedoluki/1/edit?js,output